# Angular 2 shared component error

Tags: angular, components, shared

I created a component to be shared by multiple other components. I declared the common component into Module A, it worked fine. I went and did the same in Module B, I got this error.

Type PagerComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: ModuleA and ModuleB! Please consider moving PagerComponent to a higher module that imports ModuleA and ModuleB. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes PagerComponent then import that NgModule in ModuleA and ModuleB.

So then I created a Pager Module (NgModule).

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'; 
import { PagerComponent } from '../shared/pager.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [ 
        PagerComponent
    ]
})
export class PagerModule {}
```

I then imported this new module into ModuleA and Module B. I get error:

```
Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'PagerModule'
```

This error is not telling me what is wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I see the issue with your `NgModule` declaration.
Thanks to `NgModule` structure you cannot pass anything other than `NgModule`'s in to `imports` field. In your case you need to pass `PagerComponent` to `declarations` and `exports` fields of module.

In `declarations` you, obviously, declare your components, pipes and directives. Also you need to pass those into `exports` section in order to make them "visible" for other components in the target module

E.g.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'; 
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { PagerComponent } from '../shared/pager.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [ CommonModule ],
    declarations: [ PagerComponent ],
    exports: [ PagerComponent ]
})
export class PagerModule {}
```